# Django annotate queryset on a specific value of relational model attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose there is a structure like this:

```
PARTICIPATION_STATUSES = (
    (0, 'No, thanks'),
    (1, 'I may attend'),
    (2, 'I\'ll be there'),
)

class Model1(models.Model):
    # ...

class Model2(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _('participation status'), choices=PARTICIPATION_STATUSES)    
    field = models.ForeignKey(Model1, related_name='model1_participation')
```

What I want to do is to annotate each object of `Model1` with count of `Model2` objects where status equals a specific value (status number is this particular example).

In my pseudo code it would look like:

```
queryset = Model1.objects.all()
queryset.annotate(declined=Count('model1_participation__status=0'))
queryset.annotate(not_sure=Count('model1_participation__status=1'))
queryset.annotate(accepted=Count('model1_participation__status=2'))
```

But I can't annotate the queryset in this way as Django doesn't resolve `status=<n>`.

What is the right way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.8 or above you can use [Conditional Aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation), these should work for `annotate` querysets.

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Case, When, Count


queryset = Model1.objects.all()

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    declined=Count(
        Case(When(model1_participation__status=0, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    not_sure=Count(
        Case(When(model1_participation__status=1, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    ),
    accepted=Count(
        Case(When(model1_participation__status=2, then=1),
             output_field=IntegerField())
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks realy good, but I need to annotate objects and not to aggregate. Do you have any ideas on annotatios like these?

Comment: I've modified the answer, it should still work the same way. Give it a shot and let me know how it goes!

Comment: Given the models, I don't think `field_set` is the correct name (`_set` is used for objects, i.e. to retrieve the related records of a specific instance). Use `When(model2__status==...` rather

Comment: @Pynchia you are probably right there. I've updated it.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, I made it work with a few edits :) First of all I am not sure why @Pynchia pointed about changing `_set` -> `model2`, Django doesn't resolve `model2`, it has to be `_set`. Another thing is that It's necessary to re initialize the object when calling `annotate` method so it has to look like `queryset = queryset.annotate(...) `.

I've struggled much on this question, haven't seen `Conditional Aggregations` anywhere before so thanks for your help!

Comment: @pythad [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) you can have a look for yourself at how to perform a query on related models. e.g. `Reporter.objects.filter(article__pk=1)` with your models would be `Model1.objects.filter(model2__status=1)`. Therefore, if you are using `_set` it means there is some other code you have forgotten to mention (i.e. the query is performed on a specific record/instance of 'model1`. Maybe iterating?)

Comment: @Pynchia, I simplified my question a bit. There is a related_name in my project, i query on it. Just messed up related name with _set. I am sorry, thanks for your pointing.

Comment: OK, then to make the question helpful for others, please do edit you models in the question and add the `related_name` parameter to `field` in `Model2`. Your question is __very relevant__ and there aren't many useful answers (recent ones). So the answer you got will be quite useful indeed to the Django community

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Exists Subquery:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Exists, ExpressionWrapper, OuterRef, Subquery, Value
from django.db.models.fields import BooleanField

queryset = Model1.objects.all()
queryset.annotate(
  declined=ExpressionWrapper(
    Exists(Model2.objects.filter(                        
      field=OuterRef('id'),
      status=0)),
    output_field=BooleanField()))),
  not_sure=ExpressionWrapper(
    Exists(Model2.objects.filter(
      field=OuterRef('id'),
      status=1)),
    output_field=BooleanField()))),
  accepted=ExpressionWrapper(
    Exists(Model2.objects.filter(                        
      field=OuterRef('id'),
      status=2)),
    output_field=BooleanField())))
)
```

To make it a bit more clear/reusable you can refactor into a function:

```
def is_status(status_code):
   return ExpressionWrapper(
     Exists(Model2.objects.filter(                        
        field=OuterRef('id'),
        status=status_code)),
     output_field=BooleanField())))

Model1.objects.annotate(
  declined=is_status(0),
  not_sure=is_status(1),
  accepted=is_status(2)
)
```